# Converting SVD code from MATLAB to Python

Tags: python, matlab, computer-vision, svd

I have some code in MATLAB that I need to convert to Python, centred around SVD. With equal inputs I cannot get the same result. Does anyone have any ideas where I am going wrong?

MATLAB code

```
function v = homography_solve(pin, pout)
% HOMOGRAPHY_SOLVE finds a homography from point pairs
%   V = HOMOGRAPHY_SOLVE(PIN, POUT) takes a 2xN matrix of input vectors and
%   a 2xN matrix of output vectors, and returns the homogeneous
%   transformation matrix that maps the inputs to the outputs, to some
%   approximation if there is noise.
%
%   This uses the SVD method of
%   http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/presentations/bmvc97/criminispaper/node3.html
% David Young, University of Sussex, February 2008
if ~isequal(size(pin), size(pout))
    error('Points matrices different sizes');
end
if size(pin, 1) ~= 2
    error('Points matrices must have two rows');
end
n = size(pin, 2);
if n < 4
    error('Need at least 4 matching points');
end
% Solve equations using SVD
x = pout(1, :); y = pout(2,:); X = pin(1,:); Y = pin(2,:);
rows0 = zeros(3, n);
rowsXY = -[X; Y; ones(1,n)];
hx = [rowsXY; rows0; x.*X; x.*Y; x];
hy = [rows0; rowsXY; y.*X; y.*Y; y];
h = [hx hy];
if n == 4
    [U, ~, ~] = svd(h);
else
    [U, ~, ~] = svd(h, 'econ');
end
v = (reshape(U(:,9), 3, 3)).';
end
```

```
pin =

  [167.4787  300.2447  430.9681  114.3723  298.2021  479.9894;
  200.5000  199.1383  202.5426  226.3723  228.4149  228.4149]

pout = 
   [-3.0500         0    3.0500   -3.0500         0    3.0500;
    6.7050    6.7050    6.7050    1.9800    1.9800    1.9800]

This returns 

v =    

   [-0.0006   -0.0000    0.1934;
   -0.0000    0.0040   -0.9801;
    0.0000   -0.0004    0.0449]
```

The current code I have in Python is below but does not give similar results. It will return a 3x3 matrix but not like that from MATLAB.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg

def homography_solve(pin, pout):
    # Check if input and output matrices have the same size
    if pin.shape != pout.shape:
        raise ValueError('Points matrices different sizes')
    
    # Check if the matrices have two rows
    if pin.shape[0] != 2:
        raise ValueError('Points matrices must have two rows')
    
    n = pin.shape[1]
    
    # Check if we have at least 4 matching points
    if n < 4:
        raise ValueError('Need at least 4 matching points')
    
    # Solve equations using SVD
    x = pout[0, :]
    y = pout[1, :]
    X = pin[0, :]
    Y = pin[1, :]
    
    rows0 = np.zeros((3, n))
    rowsXY = np.vstack((-X, -Y, -np.ones(n)))
    hx = np.vstack((rowsXY, rows0, x * X, x * Y, x))
    hy = np.vstack((rows0, rowsXY, y * X, y * Y, y))
    h = np.hstack((hx, hy))
    

    if n == 4:
        U, sdiag, VH = np.linalg.svd(h)
    else:
        U, sdiag, VH = np.linalg.svd(h, full_matrices=False)
        
    S = np.zeros((h.shape[0], h.shape[1]))
    np.fill_diagonal(S, sdiag)
    V = VH.T.conj() 
    
    v = (U[-1,:].reshape(3, 3)).T
    
    return v
```

Comment: please show what you are expecting to get back in python...

Comment: also,  you have imported `linalg` from `scipy`, but in the code you use `np.linalg`.....  did you mean to do this ?

Comment: and finally `pin.shape`  and `pout.shape` are not defined. presumably they are numpy arrays containing 2 rows....

Comment: I would expect to get v as in the Matlab code.

linalg and scipy are both imported as some resources suggested one or the other hence both are imported but one used 
pin.shape[0] refers to the number of rows and pin.shape[1] the number of columns - or at least it should

Answer (score 0):

The reference `v` you show is a non-solution, and a back-multiply with your reference `pin` does not look like `pout` at all. So the code not giving similar results is a good thing - but the output of the Python solution is also wrong. The simplest solution is one call to `lstsq`:

```py
import numpy as np


def homography_solve(pin: np.ndarray, pout: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    if pin.shape != pout.shape:
        raise ValueError('Points matrices different sizes')

    return np.linalg.lstsq(
        a=np.hstack((pin.T, np.ones(shape=(pin.shape[1], 1), dtype=pin.dtype))),
        b=pout.T,
        rcond=None,
    )[0]


ain = np.array([
    [167.4787,  300.2447,  430.9681,  114.3723,  298.2021,  479.9894],
    [200.5000,  199.1383,  202.5426,  226.3723,  228.4149,  228.4149],
])
aout = np.array([
      [-3.0500,         0,    3.0500,   -3.0500,         0,    3.0500],
      [ 6.7050,    6.7050,    6.7050,    1.9800,    1.9800,    1.9800],
])
output = homography_solve(ain, aout)
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=200)
print(output)
print(aout)
print(output.T @ np.vstack((ain, np.ones(6))))
```

```
[[ 1.88837036e-02  1.10075526e-03]
 [ 1.72936013e-03 -1.74139133e-01]
 [-6.00807070e+00  4.13197913e+01]]
[[-3.05   0.     3.05  -3.05   0.     3.05 ]
 [ 6.705  6.705  6.705  1.98   1.98   1.98 ]]
[[-2.49871587e+00  6.04304700e-03  2.48047224e+00 -3.45681886e+00  1.81009790e-02  3.45091846e+00]
 [ 6.58924815e+00  6.97251628e+00  6.52358890e+00  2.02541110e+00  1.87206612e+00  2.07216945e+00]]
```

Your data are over-determined; if you cut a few columns out of your inputs the solution becomes exact:

```
[[ 2.30741752e-02 -2.05810916e-17]
 [ 9.88907056e-03  2.15105711e-16]
 [-8.89719152e+00  6.70500000e+00]]
[[-3.05   0.     3.05 ]
 [ 6.705  6.705  6.705]]
[[-3.05   0.     3.05 ]
 [ 6.705  6.705  6.705]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Essentially the solution above is meant to give 3D coordinates (assuming they lie in a plane e.g., ground where z coordinate = 0) using the 2D coordinates in pixels from a single image. So the code should take the coordinates in pixels (pin) with their known locations (pout) and v should be the matrix that converts coordinates (pixels) into 3D coordinates in the real world. Any other code that could do this is much appreciated. The code above was based around needing a minimum of 4 points but then a best fit for more than 5 points (or that's what I thought).

Comment: That's what this does, no?

Comment: I have two new coordinates that I am trying to find.

array([[296.79422895],
       [203.24645222]])

array([[428.0672238 ],
       [464.78329654]])

These should both come out to around (0,6) and (0,-6.5). The second coordinate is coming out way off. I'm not sure why. The first one is giving me an appropriate value.